# Unit testing of potential concurrency problems

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, thread-safety

I have had recently a small contest with one of my colleagues (whom I very respect) regarding a theoretical possibility to test whether some code is thread-safe or not.

Let us suppose that we have a some "black-box" class `FooUnknown` taken from the 3rd party library, so we don't have an access to its original source code. Furthermore, it might be that it internally uses some native methods (if this is a matter).

Can we write such an unit test which will tell us that usage of this class (for example, its instance shared between several threads) is 100% thread-safe or not?

My conclusion, that **it is not possible**. For me it is obvious and straightforward: although one can write a code which will lead to some concurrency problems which is possible to detect. But an absent of such results doesn't guarantee that there are not concurrency issues at all.

Also I believe, that this question is not **too broad**. For certainty let us say we have a class `some.FooUnknown` and we want to use it in the following way:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FooService {
    private some.FooUnkown foo = new some.FooUnknown();

    public void someStuff() {
        // ...
        String result = foo.doSomeStuff();
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to test it to be sure that it is thread-safe, that we don't need to wrap it into `ThreadLocal<FooUnknown>` for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible, because there are to many ways to produce thread unsafety. Just a global variable in native code could be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring all practical reasons, this is also why it's theoretically hard to achieve a complete set of concurrency safety tests:

Assuming there are `n` threads operating on the same data structure. Then any thread `i` has a sequence of S<sub>i</sub> atomic operations on this datastructure, where each sequence may have a different length. Now what you need to make sure in an ideal environment is that every possible iteration sequence across all threads through these operation is covered by your tests. Even for relatively small operation sequences and only 2 threads this number grows quite fast.

But now the difficult part is to translate these findings to a real computer. Identifying such atomic operations itself is a complex task of its own, given the freedom of how jvms can be implemented and the java memory model. Then there is also thread scheduling controlled by os. So it's usually out of your control what actual operation sequence takes place on the data structure.

Comment: Man, even Halting problem is unsolvable algorithmically. What are you talking about?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Unfortunately your question is too unspecific for me to improve my answer.

Comment: I just pointed out that it's nothing "theoretical" in your answer.

Comment: plus 1 to everyone, but idea with global variable seemed to me the best

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - as a black box, you can't possibly say if it's thread safe or not.. Even if you test it for 2 weeks and throw everything at it on a million VMs, maybe it is thread-safe now, but will become thread-unsafe in 2018 (e.g. by internally checking what the date is and intentionally dead-locking on 2018-01-01)

Comment: Totally agree with you. But I want to keep this question open in order to give a chance for opposite side provide their tricky ideas :-) Upvoting the question also can cause increasing of the interest to it :)

Comment: Actually if we limit ourselves to thread safety for one particular ISA this is theoretically doable. Just execute every possible permutation of instructions for every possible input (both of which must be finite) and check whether the output is identical for every possible instruction sequence for every possible input. Not very practical but guaranteed to work.

Comment: (The trick here to counteract your example is that "get current date" would be an input so you'd have to check the output for every possible value).

Comment: @Voo that's interesting point, but you can not guarantee absent of the instructions reordering during you test. You can not forcibly cause it, so you can not be sure that even it happens, you are free from problems: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering

Comment: And looking at its instructions wouldn't exactly be black-box testing.. If you can look inside, it's probably at least 4 times faster to just reverse engineer it, compared to running all possible permutations on all possible inputs..

Comment: @Andremony But that's the beauty of the argument, even if the CPU has internal state that influences behavior that's just more state you have to control for (and in practice things like reordering are deterministic based on rather little state).

Comment: @xs4 What's the theoretical argument to prove arbitrary Java code is thread safe? (apart from executing it). And I guess it depends on the definition of black box testing.. the OP defined it as "don't have an access to its original source code" which you don't need for this. But yes it's all a question of definitions.

Comment: @Voo afaik, it's quite impossible to prove thread safety for arbitrary code (unless it's obviously/trivially so, e.g. by being a semi-pure function with no state which could even be visible to other threads). Usually code that is meant to be thread-safe is so by construction..

Comment: @Voo and here's an argument for that not being possible even in theory - either you assume infinite time or finite time. If time is infinite, you have to test infinite possible executions, which obviously can never finish. And if time is finite, you have to take into account the number of interleavings can be arbitrarily big. So, assuming e.g. nanosecond-precision clocks, you'd have to test all possible interleavings for each possible nanosecond faster than in one nanosecond, otherwise you eventually run out of time (it's finite). So it's a no go for any finite amount of computing power..

Comment: @Voo the problem with that approach is that, even if you had the technology to do this, it would catch only one possible source of thread safety problems : race conditions.

Comment: @xs0 That argument doesn't hold. You can't work with infinities in that way. If you have a finite number of steps that all take a finite amount of time the sun of it will be finite.

Comment: @bowmore There's also visibility to consider, but that's the thing: That's simply part of the CPU state. This really is no witch craft, but a very simple idea: If you have a finite-state machine and finite input you will always get a result in finite time. The possible input is finite if we're going with current knowledge of our universe and the FSM describes the language and CPU ISA - which absolutely is finite. The thing is this is only theoretically useful thanks to the state explosion problem.

Comment: What we're talking about is nothing but the basics of model checking and temporal logic in particular. [Here's a nice introduction into the whole matter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a425/7cd9abde220d55d777da6c061671b63f8bf2.pdf).

Comment: @Voo sure, finite*finite = finite. But I'm saying that if the code is looking at the clock, every possible timestamp that can exist introduces a whole new execution possibility to verify. So, each single execution/verification (on average) would need to take less time than what the clock step is, introducing an upper bound on execution time. So, it's no longer enough for the verification time to be finite, it has to be relatively "small" as well. And so, for any finite compute capacity, you can construct code that takes too long to verify, and the process in its entirety won't ever finish.

Comment: @xs0 Only if you had an infinitely large data type to store date times. You don't though, which is at the heart of the problem.

Comment: @Voo, well then, that's actually another argument that it's impossible - even if you somehow manage to get there, sooner or later, your entire memory capacity will be spent on storing the timestamp, and you will have no memory left for execution.. :) And if the capacity is allowed to be finite but growing, we can surely take an extra byte now and then to store the ever bigger timestamp (which only grows logarithmically)..

Comment: @xs0 Yeah which is why I said "no practical solution", just that there is a theoretical algorithm that works for any LBA. But yes you basically rediscovered the state explosion problem I mentioned earlier :-) (Another poignant example: The state for even an ancient PDP-8 from the 60s is larger than the number of atoms in the observable universe - and that by far! It's really not a practical solution to anything, although model checking can be made to work quite well with more practical approaches)

Comment: @Voo I can agree with that.. I guess a clock makes a computer a non-LBA, though? never thought of that before, tbh :)

Comment: @Voo I understand what you are saying, but it does not follow that finite input on a FSM will get you a result in finite time. Some code exists to keep doing tasks indefinitely. And such code may prove to be not thread safe after an indefinite amount of time. This renders it, not just practically, but also theoretically impossible to fully test for thread safety.

Comment: @bowmore "but it does not follow that finite input on a FSM will get you a result in finite time"... that follows from the  definition of a FSM actually. For every input you transition from one state to another. If you have finite input, there'll be a finite number of transitions meaning you'll end up in a some state after finite time.

Comment: @Voo i see, then my point is that for a black box component, you cannot simply assume it will generate a finite input to the FSM